# Indexing with DatetimeIndex returning Int64Index?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am running into a strange problem with the following versions of:

- Pandas: `0.14.1`
- Python: `3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)`

I have a series like the following (data available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_X48YFVS7SSURlUGhmWFp4bk0/view?usp=sharing))

```
> my_series.head()

timestamp
2014-10-14 19:00:05.861000-04:00    6.4400
2014-10-14 19:00:07.094000-04:00    6.4400
2014-10-14 19:00:07.109000-04:00    5.9584
2014-10-14 19:00:07.211000-04:00    6.2160
2014-10-14 19:00:07.410000-04:00    6.4400
Name: quantity, dtype: float64
```

The index is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
> my_series.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-10-14 19:00:05.861000-04:00, ..., 2014-10-14 19:06:35.307000-04:00]
Length: 2042, Freq: None, Timezone: US/Eastern
```

The index has duplicates (and I need those entries to be there):

```
> my_series.index.get_duplicates()

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-10-14 23:00:10.825000, ..., 2014-10-14 23:05:49.029000]
Length: 65, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

#### Sampling from it:

Now, say I want to sample this series at specific time points using a `pandas.tseries.indexDatetimeIndex` object `ts`:

```
> import arrow
> start_time = arrow.get(2014, 10, 14, hour = 19, tzinfo='US/Eastern')
> end_time   = start_time.replace(seconds=400)
> ts = pd.date_range(start=start_time.isoformat(), 
                     end=end_time.isoformat(), 
                     freq='2200L')
```

Note that:

```
> start_time.isoformat()
2014-10-14T19:00:00-04:00
> end_time.isoformat()
2014-10-14T19:06:40-04:00
```

and

```
> ts
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-10-14 19:00:00-04:00, ..., 2014-10-14 19:06:40.400000-04:00]
Length: 183, Freq: 2200L, Timezone: tzoffset(None, -14400)
```

When I sample it:

```
> my_series[ts].head()
1413327600000000000   NaN
1413327602200000000   NaN
1413327604400000000   NaN
1413327606600000000   NaN
1413327608800000000   NaN
Name: quantity, dtype: float64
```

I get a series indexed by an `int64` index, and **not** the `DatetimeIndex` index (from `ts`) that I would expect:

```
> my_series.ix[ts].index
Int64Index([1412636400000000000, 1412636402200000000, ...], dtype='int64')
```

Interestingly  the `int64` indices seem to be "correct". If I do:

```
my_series.ix[ts].index = pd.to_datetime(my_series.ix[ts].index).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

I can fix the problem.

Why does it return `int64` and not `DatetimeIndex`? How can I convert it to the latter?

Comment: show your pandas version, and exactly how you are contructing the series.

Comment: hmm the duplicates might be causing an issue - let me look

Comment: cannot replicate what you are doing. pls post a pickle of exactly your input structures and exact code to replicate.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff -- I have updated the full post with a link to data (50 KB). I keep running into the problem with different datasets, so it is easier to replicate for me. This is all using Pandas `0.14.1` and Python `Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the input I see (s from the pickle, ts generated as above), though not sure what arrow is; I am generating from isostrings

```
In [42]: ts
Out[42]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-10-14 19:00:00-04:00, ..., 2014-10-14 19:06:40.400000-04:00]
Length: 183, Freq: 2200L, Timezone: pytz.FixedOffset(-240)

In [43]: s.index
Out[43]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-10-14 19:00:05.861000-04:00, ..., 2014-10-14 19:06:35.307000-04:00]
Length: 2042, Freq: None, Timezone: US/Eastern
```

You don't have any overlapping values

```
In [41]: s.index.tz_convert('UTC').isin(ts.tz_convert('UTC')).any()
Out[41]: False
```

I cannot reproduce the error where the index is NOT a DatetimeIndex. Note that this is on 0.15.0 (releasing today). And a lot of fixes went thru for tz types of things.

You are doing a really odd comparison that won't work anyhow. In order to select/reindex these have to be the same tz, otherwise it doesn't make any sense.